# How to install mysql without root access?

Tags: software-installation, mysql, root

I found [this article](http://www.bluecrownsoftware.com/article/271/Installing-MySQL-without-Root-Access-on-Linux) that explains how to install MySQL without root access. However, on the [MySQL download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) is no download link for Ubuntu. Which one should I choose in this case?

If it has a "generic linux" choice that claims to be architecture-independent, why does it need all the other dependent ones?

Lastly, I don't know its dependencies. Since I cannot use a package manager (because I don't have root - Yargs!), I need to resolve everything manually. How do I do that?

Comment: Why is using the package manager a problem? Is this your own Ubuntu installation or are you accessing a public or corporate server? If private, you can just use `sudo`. Then is should be as easy as `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` to install MySql on Ubuntu without root access (just use your own user's password if you installed Ubuntu yourself).

Comment: As mentioned in the title, I don't have root access to the machine. If I try to sudo, it tells me: "<my user name> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: Then you must not be the system admin? In that case ask the system admin to add your user to the sudoers file.

Comment: I can't. Its a university machine. I already talked to the admin and he said he would generally not recommend using mysql because its such a pain to install without root (and evidently, they are not willing to install it for me). However, I need it.

Comment: Then you unfortunately need to resolve that with them, there is no trivial way of bypassing (effectively, hacking) the restrictions that are in place for a server that you do not control. If you need  access to MySql consider installing on your own (or a friend's) conputer instead? For pure educational purposes you might consider free MySql database access to play around: http://www.freesqldatabase.com/freemysqldatabase/

Comment: @Werner whats the advantage of freemysql?

Comment: It depends on why you want to use MySql. If you are a student, and want to learn about MySQl, then that's a way to get access to a free database on which you can experiment and learn, without having to install MySql yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a package manager you can download **source code**. At the website you posted choose "Source Code" and then take the generic one: "Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive". Now you have to compile the source code. There are plenty of guides how to compile mysql manually.

---

Another option would be to download the **Debian package** from the list and unpack it manually:

```
ar x package.deb
tar xzf data.tar.gz
```

Then you find the binaries in the folder you unpacked the data.tar.gz.

---

But be aware, it is a pain, because you have to do this with all the libraries needed by mysql, too

Comment: Why not install the Generic Linux binary version instead of the Debian one? Why are Debian packages compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: Because Ubuntu is based on debian